# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'taggable_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to set up [laravel-tagging](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging), which seems to be the most popular tagging system for Laravel out there. But unfortunately it doesn't come with any front-end features. There is a [guide](https://laravel-news.com/2015/10/how-to-add-tagging-to-your-laravel-app) for it that I followed through thoroughly. At the end, I run into error while trying to create a tag:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'taggable_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `tagging_tagged`
>   (`tag_name`, `tag_slug`, `taggable_type`, `taggable_id`) values
>   (Cheese, cheese, App\Links, ))

I found several other posts where people ran into similar errors, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029277/problems-with-laravel-many-to-many-polymorphic-relationships), [this](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging/issues/19) and [this](https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging/issues/17). But none of them provide a definitive solution. People, and the common sense, say that the model that contains `taggable_id` should be saved so the tag gets stored in the database. My code for the controller looks like this:

```
public function storeStuff(Request $request)
{
    // Create the link first
    $link = new Links;

    // Now add tags
    $link->tag(explode(',', $request->tags));

    // Try to save tags?
    $link->save();
}
```

My attempt to save it using `$link->save();` in my case doesn't work. I still get the same error and my database table `tagging_tagged`, which contains `taggable_id` column is still full of nulls. Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this problem?

**EDIT:** I got it to work by adding another save as suggested by Tobias Karlsson:

```
    $link = new Links;
    $link->tag_name = $request->tags;
    $link->save();

    // Now add tags
    $link->tag(explode(',', $request->tags));

    $link->save();
```

I also had to add timestamps to fix missing `created_at` error. Timestamps are not included in initial migration that comes with laravel-tagging package, even though I am not sure if they are useful for tags. My `tagging_tagged` table now looks like this:

```
FIELD         TYPE              NULL   KEY
id            int(10)unsigned   NO     PRI      auto_increment
taggable_id   int(10)unsigned   NO     MUL      
taggable_type varchar(255)      NO     MUL      
tag_name      varchar(255)      NO          
tag_slug      varchar(255)      NO     MUL      
created_at    timestamp         YES         
updated_at    timestamp         YES
```

I am still trying to get Javascript to autofill tags. I will update this question once I get it all working.

Comment: I think `taggable_id` is a foreign key and you can not enter NULL data for the same. So, either remove the constraint or add some value for that column.

Comment: Is `taggable_id` a primary key? Can you paste the output of the following SQL query: `DESCRIBE tagging_tagged`

Comment: Basically You are trying to tag a resource which does not have `id` yet. You have to first save it, to gain id, then try to add tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to save the model first and then set tags and then save again.

```
$link = new Links;
$link->someProperty = $request->someProperty;

// Save model to get a taggable_id (model id).
$link->save();

// Now add tags
$link->tag(explode(',', $request->tags));

// Save tags.
$link->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to set `DEFAULT NULL` for taggable_id in table structure or else you have to add NULL in query like this.

```
insert into tagging_tagged (tag_name, tag_slug, taggable_type, taggable_id) values (Cheese, cheese, App\Links, NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may come late but should be helpful to others trying to implement tagging within their work. If you already understood [Laravel-tags](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-tags/v2/basic-usage/using-tags/), then you may see a gap in their explanation and how they made it more difficult for laymen like me from understanding their package. Taking the sample of Tobias Karlsson (above) and modifying.

```
$link = new Links;

//you shouldn't add any tag property in the line below
$link->someProperties = $request->someProperties;

//save model to get taggable_id (model_id)
$link->save();

//now add tags
$link->attachTags(['tag1','tag2','tag3']);
$link->save();
```