# laravel-tagging creates double entries in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to set up `laravel-tagging` system and get it to store tags in the database. However, it creates double entries every time I submit an article with tags:

```
 id    taggable_id   taggable_type    tag_name    tag_slug
'72',    '128',      
'73',    '72',      'App\Article',   'Newtag1',  'newtag1'
```

The first entry (`id=72`) has a correct `taggable_id` and the second entry (`id=73`) is created automatically by `laravel-tagging` and automatically sets another `taggable_id` to `72`, which has been counting up since zero and behaves like an auto-increment. But it has no auto-increment setting in the database schema.

Here is how I set it up:

1) I create a new model instance:

```
$article = new Article;
```

2) Then I assign a `taggable_id`, which is the id of a post that is created with the tag:

```
$article->taggable_id = $postid;
```

3) I save the `$article` into the database:

```
$article->save();
```

4) I find the saved row in the database by the `taggable_id` and put it into a fresh `$article`:

```
$article = Article::where('taggable_id', $postid)->first();
```

5) I run `laravel-tagging`'s `tag` method to get the tag into the database:

```
$article->tag($request->taggone);
```

6) I save the row again

```
$article->save();
```

And this gives me the double entry shown in the beginning. Why is that happening? What am I doing wrong? I just want it to use the original entry to store those tags, not create a new one.

**EDIT:** I tried skipping step 4, the outcome is the same.

**EDIT2** My `Article` model looks like this:

```
namespace App;

use Conner\Tagging\Taggable;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use Taggable;

    protected $table = 'tagging_tagged';

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need steps 3 and 4? Create the tag instance completely once, and then save it to database.

Comment: @KaranPunamiya If I do not save it I get an error `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'taggable_id' cannot be null `. I even created a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132856/integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-taggable-id-cannot-be-null) and the only way I could get around it is to save it ahead of using `tag` function.

Comment: Can you show us your `Article` model?

Comment: @user3158900 Sure, I updated my question with the model

Comment: That's what I figured was going wrong.  The table should not be `tagging_tagged`.  It should be `articles` or whatever table you are storing your articles in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is because you set the `$table` property on your `Article` model to the `tags` table when it should remain the `articles` table.

The general idea of this is everything stays the same for the most part with `laravel-tagging`.  The only difference is if you want a certain model, such as `Article` to support tagging, all you'd need to do is add the `use Conner\Tagging\Taggable;` statement to your model.

Then you create articles just like you always would.  For example

```
$article = new Article();
$article->title 'Test Article';
$article->body = 'Some article body';
$article->save();  // Should save it first before trying to tag
```

Then if you wanted to add a tag to the article

```
$article->tag('Gardening');  // This will tag this article
```

You shouldn't need to worry about setting any of the columns on the `tagging_tagged` table, the extension will handle that for you when you use `tag()`.

Comment: I just had the biggest facepalm in the history of facepalms. I spent three days banging my head against the wall looking for a solution and it was this simple. You have my deep bow, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make laravel-tagging with this method:
First create News model

```
class News extends Model {
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag', 'news');
    }  
}
```

Then create Tag model

```
class Tag extends Model {
    public function getNews()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\News', 'news');
    }
}
```

Afterwards you should create a controller to insert the news with tags.

```
public function postCreate(Request $request)
{
    //here you will insert your own datas
    $news = new News();
    $news -> description = $request->description;
    $news -> title = $request->title;
    $news -> save();

    foreach ($request->tags as $t)
    {
       $tags = new Tag();
       $tags->tag = $t;
       $tags->lang = $request->lang;
       $news->tags()->save($tags);
    }
}
```

This is your html

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="title"> <br>
   <input type="text" name="description"> <br>
   <input type="text" name="tags[]">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And this is your sql data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `news` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lang` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tag` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```