# PHP: Call to a member function contains() on string

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a simple crud app in which I want the user to be able to add tags as they wish.

I am using this plugin [eloquent-taggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-taggable/tree/3.5)

I have followed the instruction as per GitHub docs.

Here is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $pages =new PageList([
        'pagetitle' => $request->get('pagetitle'),
        'articlelist' => $request->get('articlelist'),
        'tags' => $request->get('tags'),
        'status' => $request->get('status'),
        'prebid' => $request->get('prebid'),
    ]);

    $pages->save();

    $tags =explode(',', $request->tags);
    $pages->tag($tags);
    $pages->save();

    return redirect('/pages')->with('success', 'data saved!');
}
```

> UPDATE

When I do `dd($tags);` I get this

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "dfdf"
  1 => "hjhjhj"
]
```

> UPDATE

here is result of `dd($request->get('tags'));`

[image]

Now when I add tags and click button save I get the following error

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Call to a member function contains() on string

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: @user996422 show $request->tags  output here..

Comment: check update on my question

Comment: share the screenshot please

Comment: whats in `$request->get('tags')`?

Comment: use `dd($request->get('tags'))` or `dd($request->tags)` NOT `dd($tags)`

Comment: what exactly you want ? You want to store the array of data in to `tag` column of `pagelist` right ?

Comment: I have updated as per your rquest guys, check it

Comment: can you share stack trace?

Comment: You already assign tags with value coming from `$request`.What is the need for exploding and saving again ?

Comment: here is my repo https://github.com/throne1986/royalad-dahsboard/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PageListController.php

Comment: @jitheshjose I used exmple from this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132856/integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-taggable-id-cannot-be-null   please check it out ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the library but I dont think you need to save the model again, also the tags need to be trimmed so try this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $pages =new PageList([
        'pagetitle' => $request->get('pagetitle'),
        'articlelist' => $request->get('articlelist'),
        'tags' => $request->get('tags'),
        'status' => $request->get('status'),
        'prebid' => $request->get('prebid'),
    ]);

    $pages->save();

    $tags =explode(', ', $request->tags); //note the change here from ',' to ', '
    $pages->tag($tags);//no need to save model again

    return redirect('/pages')->with('success', 'data saved!');
}
```

Looks like a known issue, specific to the plugin, check the issue here: https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-taggable/issues/55

Comment: still the same ,` Call to a member function contains() on string`

Comment: here is my repo `https://github.com/throne1986/royalad-dahsboard/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PageListController.php`

Comment: Look at the issue link i gave in my answer

Comment: I am checking but I can't see any solution :(

Comment: The link you provided says about null not a string problem :(

Answer (score 0):

After debuging and googling plust stckoverflow I found a solution

Here is my solution

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $pages =new PageList([
        'pagetitle' => $request->get('pagetitle'),
        'articlelist' => $request->get('articlelist'),
        // 'tags' => $request->get('tags'), // I removed this 
        'status' => $request->get('status'),
        'prebid' => $request->get('prebid'),
    ]);

    // $tags =explode(', ', $request->tags); //i removed this
    $pages->tag($pages->tags);//I added this 

    return redirect('/pages')->with('success', 'data saved!');
}
```

Now no errors, everything works as I want